# WHERE condition isn't respected

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

currently I'm working with the AdventureWorks database and playing around with some queries. I've tried to solve the following exercise:

Order all products by its ProductID, which

- received at least one price modification
- color is *'Yellow'*, *'Blue'* or *'Black'*
- are listed in the *'Helmets'* or *'Gloves'* category

This is my query:

```
SELECT pp.ProductID, pp.Name, pps.Name FROM Production.Product pp

JOIN Production.ProductCostHistory ppch
ON pp.ProductID = ppch.ProductID

JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory pps
ON pps.ProductSubcategoryID = pp.ProductSubcategoryID

WHERE pps.Name LIKE 'Helmets' OR pps.Name LIKE 'Gloves'
    AND pp.Color LIKE 'Yellow' OR pp.Color LIKE 'Blue' OR pp.Color LIKE 'Black'

GROUP BY pp.ProductID, pp.Name, pps.Name
HAVING Count(ppch.ModifiedDate) > 1
ORDER BY pp.Name ASC
```

This is my result:

[image]

Now, to pose my question. Allthough I connected two conditions with 'AND' I receive results of two other categories, which were listed further to the matching colors (*'Road Frames'* & *'Road Bikes'*) and I don't quiet understand why.

Shouldn't the result only show matches which fullfil both conditions?

I'm sure that there are probably much better ways to achieve this, but I'm fairly new to SQL and trying to get the basics.

I would really appreciate some help

Comment: read about precedence in logical conditions whith `OR` and `AND`

Comment: Use braces in your conditions ... actually it's interpreted as : WHERE pps.Name LIKE 'Helmets' OR (pps.Name LIKE 'Gloves'
    AND pp.Color LIKE 'Yellow') OR pp.Color LIKE 'Blue' OR pp.Color LIKE 'Black'

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I simply forgot the brackets :-/

Comment: And you should learn about `IN` (quickly). Your use of `LIKE` is totally inappropriate; at the very least you should be using  `=` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your WHERE clause to explicitly indicate groups of conditions instead of allow the precedence of ANDs and ORs determine the result.

```
WHERE
(pps.Name LIKE 'Helmets' OR pps.Name LIKE 'Gloves')
    AND
    (pp.Color LIKE 'Yellow' OR pp.Color LIKE 'Blue' OR pp.Color LIKE 'Black')
```

or better

```
WHERE pps.Name IN('Helmets','Gloves')
    AND
    pp.Color IN ('Yellow','Blue','Black')
```